# High CPU consumption, 33% battery, suddenly MacBook Pro Retina shuts down saying it needs to be plugged in

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power, shutdown

High CPU consumption, 33% battery, suddenly MacBook Pro Retina shuts down saying it needs to be plugged in.

I plug it in and then Mac works fine and battery level is at 33%.

I googled this, found nothing.

Any idea what might be wrong ?

Battery needs replacement ?

Battery looks ok:

```
Battery Information:

  Model Information:
  Serial Number:    D863016Q037F9Y2A9
  Manufacturer: SMP
  Device Name:  bq20z451
  Pack Lot Code:    0
  PCB Lot Code: 0
  Firmware Version: 511
  Hardware Revision:    000a
  Cell Revision:    1150
  Charge Information:
  Charge Remaining (mAh):   2656
  Fully Charged:    No
  Charging: Yes
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   6827
  Health Information:
  Cycle Count:  587
  Condition:    Normal
  Battery Installed:    Yes
  Amperage (mA):    2711
  Voltage (mV): 12002

System Power Settings:

  AC Power:
  System Sleep Timer (Minutes): 0
  Disk Sleep Timer (Minutes):   0
  Display Sleep Timer (Minutes):    5
  Wake on AC Change:    No
  Wake on Clamshell Open:   Yes
  Wake on LAN:  Yes
  AutoPowerOff Delay:   14400
  AutoPowerOff Enabled: 1
  Current Power Source: Yes
  DarkWakeBackgroundTasks:  1
  Display Sleep Uses Dim:   Yes
  GPUSwitch:    2
  Hibernate Mode:   3
  PrioritizeNetworkReachabilityOverSleep:   0
  Standby Delay:    4200
  Standby Enabled:  1
  Battery Power:
  System Sleep Timer (Minutes): 30
  Disk Sleep Timer (Minutes):   0
  Display Sleep Timer (Minutes):    2
  Wake on AC Change:    No
  Wake on Clamshell Open:   Yes
  AutoPowerOff Delay:   14400
  AutoPowerOff Enabled: 1
  DarkWakeBackgroundTasks:  0
  Display Sleep Uses Dim:   Yes
  GPUSwitch:    2
  Hibernate Mode:   3
  Reduce Brightness:    Yes
  Standby Delay:    4200
  Standby Enabled:  1

Hardware Configuration:

  UPS Installed:    No

AC Charger Information:

  Connected:    Yes
  ID:   0x0aa1
  Wattage (W):  85
  Family:   0x0085
  Serial Number:    0x00935697
  Charging: Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue; I did an SMC reset.

Connect the power adapter to the Mac. On the MacBook / Pro's keyboard, hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> keys and the Power button at the same time. Release all keys and the power button at the same time – the little light on the MagSafe adapter may change colors briefly to indicate the SMC has reset.

Comment: Did it worked ? @jhegedus

Comment: will it reset the Mac ? @Joe I am in the middle of some coding with lot of windows open... need to wait a few hours until I can reset my Mac.

Comment: nop ... your hard drive will not get reset.You need to save and close all windows open.

Comment: yeah, ok I need to wait with that coz I am in the middle of some work right now, thanks for the tip !

Comment: i did it, now i need to see if problems happen again or not...

Comment: did it showing that issue occurring again.

Comment: Testing it right now. Let's see :)

Comment: Well, i still have these issues....

Comment: I've had the same issue on my MBP 15" Late 2013. The 2 resets seem to work for a short time and then I'm back to the problem. I probably need to do it regularly.